# Proof an edge in a geometric graph

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry, statistics

Suppose i take two random uniformly distributed points $X_{1},X_{2}$ in $[0,1]^{2}$. In addition i connect $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ by an edge if $||X_{1},X_{2}||_{\infty} \leq r$ where $0<r<1$ and $||X_{1},X_{2}||_{\infty}=\mathrm {max}\{|x_{1}-x_{2}|,|y_{1}-y_{2}|\}$. If $A$ is the event that there is an edge between $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ how do i prove that $P(A)=(2r-r^{2})^{2}$?

This is a lemma from the paper 'Random Geometric Problems in $[0,1]^{2}$.' Particularly lemma 1 in section 4.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us define 
$P(A|X_2)=
\int_{\max(0,x_{2,1}-r)}^{\min(1,x_{2,1}+r)}
\int_{\max(0,x_{2,2}-r)}^{\min(1,x_{2,2}+r)}dx_{1,1}dx_{1,2}$

$=\left(\min(1,x_{2,1}+r)-\max(0,x_{2,1}-r)\right)
\left(\min(1,x_{2,2}+r)-\max(0,x_{2,2}-r)\right)$

The desired result is $$P(A)=\int \int P(A|X_2=(x_{2,1},x_{2,2}))dx_{2,1} dx_{2,2}$$
which can be solved per component, i.e.
$$P(A)=\left[\int \left(\min(1,x_{2,1}+r)-\max(0,x_{2,1}-r)\right)dx_{2,1}\right]\cdot
\left[\int \left(\min(1,x_{2,2}+r)-\max(0,x_{2,2}-r)\right)dx_{2,2}\right]=\left[\int \left(\min(1,x_{2,1}+r)-\max(0,x_{2,1}-r)\right)dx_{2,1}\right]^2$$

Now let us solve
$$\int_0^1 \left(\min(1,x_{2,1}+r)-\max(0,x_{2,1}-r)\right)dx_{2,1}$$
$$=\int_0^r \min(1,x_{2,1}+r)dx_{2,1}+\int_r^1(\min(1,x_{2,1}+r)-x_{2,1}+r)dx_{2,1}$$
etc.

Comment: Feel free to accept or like.